# NullPointerException with Bluetooth data transfer in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-bluetooth

So I basically have this problem. im trying to communicate with an arduino via bluetooth, and everything was ok with sending data from the main activity to the arduino,until i tried to transfer data from my fragment to the arduino, i get thrown an error in the logcat which is:

```
**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.administradora.prueba.MainActivity$ConnectedThread.write(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference**
```

here is the ConnectedThread class to communicate....

```
public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    //creation of the connect thread
    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try {
            //Create I/O streams for connection
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }


    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        int bytes;

        // Keep looping to listen for received messages
        while (true) {
            try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);            //read bytes from input buffer
                String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity via handler
                bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //write method
    public void write(String input) {
        byte[] msgBuffer = input.getBytes();           //converts entered String into bytes
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);                //write bytes over BT connection via outstream
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //if you cannot write, close the application
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "La Conexión fallo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();

        }
    }
}`
```

And here it is my fragment java class  from where im trying to send data:

```
public class exterior extends Fragment {

public MainActivity.ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
public exterior() {

    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exterior,container,false);

    ToggleButton garage,lucext;
    garage=(ToggleButton)v.findViewById(R.id.garage);


    garage.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked){

                mConnectedThread.write("7");

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"On",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Off",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

return v;
 }
}
```

(Below is the line i added trying to fix the error, but didnt seem to work pretty much)***

```
public MainActivity.ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
```

Hope someone knows how to solve it, thanks everyone.

Comment: you never assign anything to mConnectedThread

Comment: what should i assign? please help me

Comment: You should assign `mConnectedThread` to a `new ConnectedThread` *within the Fragment*. The value from the Activity *is not shared* unless you explicitly set it.

Comment: how would i set it? to let my fragment use mConnectedthread? i want to send data from a button contained in a fragment, but it keeps throwing me an error

Comment: this is the only issue, i cant use mConnectedThread,write() from within my fragment man

Answer (score 0):

First of all your class names should start with a capital name so change exterior to Exterior

Since you said you already initialized a ConnectedThread object in the main activity, you need to make a setter method in the fragment that will set the mConnectedThread from the main Activity on the newly created fragment.

In you MainActivity where you start the fragment transaction

```
Exterior fragment = new Exterior(); 
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragment).commit();

fragment.setConnectedThread(mConnectedThread);
```

Then in your fragment add this method

```
public void setConnectedThread(MainActivity.ConnectedThread 
mConnectedThread){
    this.mConnectedThread = mConnectedThread;
}
```

Comment: fragment.setConnectedThread(mConnectedThread);

Comment: i get thrown an error with this line,says "it cannot resolve the symbol"

Comment: it sounds like you need to learn some basic java